# Show full image thumbnail

Tags: images, thumbnails

How can I set full image thumbnail on category pages? Image should be small in dimensions but not been cropped. Currently my theme WP-Davici (Solostream) use "Get The Image" plugin to generate thumbnail. you may have a look at http://ideabroad.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two different things:

> How can I set full image thumbnail on category pages

vs

> Image should be small in dimensions but not been cropped.

In order to display the *full-size image* thumbnail, use:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?>
```

In order to display a *box-resized*, rather than *hard-cropped*, image, you need to *tell WordPress to box-resize the image rather than hard-crop it*, via the [`add_image_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) call used to create the thumbnail image size..

- Hard-cropping an image means that WordPress will make the image *exactly the size* specified by the `$width` and `$height` parameters passed to `add_image_size()`.
- Box-resizing an image means that WordPress will resize the image proportionally, until the longest dimension matches the size specified by `$width` or `$height`, as appropriate.

You define this action in the `add_image_size()` call in `functions.php`, like so:

```
<?php
add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop );
?>
```

The fourth parameter, `$crop`, specifies whether to hard-crop ( `true` ) or to box-resize ( `false` ) the image.